# NSTableView.reloadData(forRowIndexes: rowIndex, columnIndexes: columnIndex) does not cause cells to update

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview

I can't seem to get `NSTableView.reloadData(forRowIndexes: rowIndex, columnIndexes: columnIndex)` to cause the `tableView` to update its cells.

Is this API not working and if so is there any other option for updating just single rows in the tableView ?

EDIT:

`reloadData()` does work.

It seems the problem may have something to do with the background thread not having a runloop or something.  I changed things up and now post a `NSNotification` and call the function and my `tableView` cells are now being refreshed.  I am using NSOperation for the background tasks.

Comment: Could you post the actual code? Does .reloadData() update?

Comment: See update above - but yes reload data works fine from the same line in the code.